# Implement a folder move function in Google Dirve

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am very new to writing any types of scripts and am trying to write a Google Apps Script to search through folders for a particular string, and if found move the folder to another folder.

I can copy a folder, but not move it since the copied folder has the same ID as the original, and deleting one deletes the other.  From what I have been able to figure out I can implement this by deleting the right child from the folder.  I've tried this in the APIs explorer and it does what I expect.

The problem is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement the example given in the [Google Drive SDK page in script.google.com](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/delete).  If I paste in the example code I get a Missing name after . operator error.  None of the scripting commands let me delete a child.

Likely this is a simple issue and arises from my trying to learn some JavaScript by doing this project, but I would appreciate any help or advice on how to implement a move function in Google Script.

The specific question is: How do I implement a move folder script? This is what I am trying, but it removes both folders:

```
while (contents.hasNext()) {
  folder = contents.next();
  name = folder.getName();
  if (name.search("XYZ") != -1) {
    moveFolder = folder;
    targetFolder.addFolder(moveFolder) moveFolder.setName('DEL_' +
      moveFolder.getName());
    removeFolder(moveFolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: You ask specific questions after some research, trial

Comment: Thanks for the feedback since I am new on stackoverflow.  The specific question is how to I implement a move folder script?  This is what I am trying, but it removes both folders:  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    folder = contents.next(); 
    name = folder.getName();
    if (name.search("XYZ") != -1) {
      moveFolder = folder; 
      targetFolder.addFolder(moveFolder)
      moveFolder.setName('DEL_'+moveFolder.getName());  
      removeFolder(moveFolder);
} }

Answer (score 6):

First, let's clear up some confusion. Two Drive-related "Services" are provided for use within Google Apps Script, [Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/), <s>and [Docslist Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/)</s>. The documentation you've referenced is for the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-sdk), which is not the same thing. If you're programming in Google Apps Script, ignore the SDK documentation.

Next, let's talk about what a folder or file *is* on Drive, and how that affects the concepts of "copy", "move" and "delete".  A file or folder may have a folder as a *parent*. In fact, it may have multiple parents. If we want to have the same file or folder "copied" to another folder, we just add it as a child to the target folder. At this point, it may look like we have two items with the same ID - but what we actually have is one item with two parents. If we then remove the file or folder from the original folder (disown it, in a way), it will be left with one parent, and this will appear like a "move". The file or folder will not have been "deleted". On the other hand, if instead of removing the parent / child relationship, we *DO* delete the file or folder, it will appear that we have "deleted both folders", as you have described.

So, your "move" script needs to add a new parent / child relationship, and remove the other.

The *Drive* starter script that is presented when you open a new script in the editor contains a function called `moveFileToFolder()`.

[image: Screenshot]

This function does what you are looking for, except that the thing it's moving is a file. However, the methods that are used for a file have cousins for folders, so you can just do some replacement to end up with `moveFolderToFolder()`:

```
/**
 * This script moves a specific folder into a given folder, and removes the folder
 * from all other folders that previously contained it. For more information on
 * interacting with files, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/drive/file
 */
function moveFolderToFolder(sourceFolderId, targetFolderId) {
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
  var currentFolders = sourceFolder.getParents();
  while (currentFolders.hasNext()) {
    var currentFolder = currentFolders.next();
    currentFolder.removeFolder(sourceFolder);
  }
  targetFolder.addFolder(sourceFolder);
};
```

If you want to deal with folder *Names*, then you need to use `getFoldersByName()` to collect all matching folders, then iterate using `next()` into the list. Here's how that function could be modified to use folder names. To simplify things, it assumes that there is just *ONE* folder with the given name, and throws an exception if that's not the case. Once we have a handle on the folders we're interested in, the balance of the function remains the same as the previous example.

```
function moveNamedFolderToFolder(sourceFolderName, targetFolderName) {
  var matchedFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName);
  if (matchedFolders.hasNext()) {
    var sourceFolder = matchedFolders.next();
    if (matchedFolders.hasNext()) throw new Error( "Source Folder Name not unique" );
  }
  matchedFolders= DriveApp.getFoldersByName(targetFolderName);
  if (matchedFolders.hasNext()) {
    var targetFolder = matchedFolders.next();
    if (matchedFolders.hasNext()) throw new Error( "Target Folder Name not unique" );
  }

  var currentFolders = sourceFolder.getParents();
  while (currentFolders.hasNext()) {
    var currentFolder = currentFolders.next();
    currentFolder.removeFolder(sourceFolder);
  }
  targetFolder.addFolder(sourceFolder);
};
```